# MVC4 pass lambda from controller to repository

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that calls a method in my repository that runs a linq to entities query to get a list of products for my application. I'd like to add the ability for a user to filter the results (something like standard price high to low, low to high, etc etc).

So I'm thinking I need to dynamically populate my orderby in the repository, but am having trouble with this. I'm shaky on generics in c#, so please bear with me.

**Controller**

```
model.Products = ProdRepo.GetProducts ((int)CategoryId, 0, 8);
```

**Model**

```
    //get a list of the products
    public List<ProductModel> GetProducts (int CategoryId, int Start, int End) 
    {
        List<ProductModel> Products = new List<ProductModel>();
        var products = (from p in db.products select p).AsEnumerable().OrderByWithDirection(x=> x.date_added, true).Where( x => x.category_id == CategoryId).Where((row, index) => index >= Start && index < End).ToList();
            if (products.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in products)
                {
                    ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
                    model.CategoryId = item.category_id;
                    model.Description = item.description;
                    model.Id = item.id;
                    model.Product = item.product1;
                    model.DateAdded = item.date_added;
                    model.Image = item.image;
                    model.Price = item.price;

                    Products.Add(model);
                }
            }
      }
```

So I'm thinking I need to pass a `Func<TSource, TKey>` from my controller, but I having trouble piecing together how to accomplish that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pass a Func to order it, is that what you meant?

Comment: @Travis, yes that is precisely what I mean.

Comment: In order to do that, the controller would need to have access to the ProductModel type, is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I know you mean, @Travis, but it's a new development project, so anything is possible.

Comment: I had thought you may need to make a call using the ProductModel type, but I think it can be avoided. See my answer below.

Comment: You really shouldnt do that. Passing around lambdas are a bad practice.

Comment: @DarthVader Can you explain what you mean? Passing lambdas is nearly essential for LINQ.

Comment: it makes testing difficult. Also it makes hard to understand the behavior of some method.

Comment: look the method, you have an IQueryable, which you convert to IEnumerable, and you load all the data, which is bad also. Then you do order by. This is also bad practice, why you wanna load all the data in at once. ie: youare losing all the benefit of using IQueryable.

Comment: Again, i would refrain from passing lambdas around. Think about it, I can have a single method, then pass in lambda for order by, then a predicate for where clause and so on, then you will have a god method that claims to do everything, and this code can break very easy .

Comment: Darth, unless I'm misunderstanding how EF works, it doesn't get the data until I call the `.ToList()` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by passing in a `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` which in this case would be

```
 public List<ProductModel> GetProducts (int CategoryId, int Start, int End, Func<IQueryable<ProductModel>, IOrderedQueryable<ProductModel>> order? = null)
 {
  //code shown in question

  if( order != null )
  {
   Products = order(Products).ToList();
  }
 }
```

And you could call it like this:

```
model.Products = ProdRepo.GetProducts ((int)CategoryId, 0, 8, order: q => q.OrderBy(prod => prod.SomeField));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the struggle is coming in because the ordering element is not always going to be the same type.  Rather than overcomplicating a fairly simple choice by passing around a genericized generic, why not just pass in the option and take it into account while building the linq query?

In the code at my workplace we'd probably achieve this with an enum, something like:

```
public enum OrderByValue
{
    DateAdded,
    Price,
    OtherChoice
}
```

Then, your query would just have a decision to make in the middle:

```
var products = (from p in db.products select p).AsEnumerable();
switch(orderByValue)
{
    case OrderByValue.DateAdded:
    products = products.OrderByWithDirection(x=> x.date_added, true);
    break;

    case OtherStuff:
    ...
}
products = products.Where( x => x.category_id == CategoryId)
    .Where((row, index) => index >= Start && index < End)
    .ToList();
```

If it is in fact just a binary choice you could also do the same without the enum and the switch, and just pass in a bool.

Comment: Prior answer by Travis J is a bit more elegant, I think.  Good thought!  Not as complicated as I was thinking it would be.